# Java method which takes unknown parameter

Tags: java

Is there a way in java to write a method which will take an unknown object as a parameter? The objects will always have a common method which the method will then need to call.  Here is an example:

```
public void aMethod (MultipleObjects object){

object.commonMethod();
// Do some stuff here
}
```

I'm not sure what this is called (if it exists) so its difficult to search on Google.

Comment: Are the objects you are passing in related in any way such as a common base class or interface?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a method that takes multiple unknown objects or are you asking how to have a shared method between different classes controlled by you? Or are you asking for something impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html):

```
interface MyInterface {

    void commonMethod();

}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    // implement `commonMethod()`

}
```

Now your method would be:

```
public void aMethod(MyInterface object) {
    ...
    object.commonMethod();
    ...
}
```

You can now pass an instance of `MyClass` (or any other class that implements `MyInterface`) to `aMethod()`.

Comment: Thank you i can't believe I was having such brain freeze.  I accepted your answer because it was the clearest and most complete solution.

Comment: @Adil so the objects you want to pass in aren't really unknown after all. They are known - and can share an interface.

Comment: @Jason Yes, i was just having a mental block and just couldn't see that i needed to create an interface and then the classes need to implement the interface.  I hadn't written the classes yet so that is why i said unknown.  I should have clarified that i controlled the objects being passed in.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make all those classes (which share the common method) to implement an interface, so you define the method like:

```
public void aMethod(SomeInterface obj) {
    obj.commonMethod();
    // ...
}
```

The interface would be:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public void commonMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is to define an interface that has just that method in it, then make sure all the classes that you might pass to aMethod implement that interface.  E.g.:

```
interface CommonMethodHaver {
     void commonMethod();
}

class Class1 implements CommonMethodHaver {
     yadda yadda yadda;
     void commonMethod() {
         do class1-specific stuff here;
     }
}

...
public void aMethod(CommonMethodHaver cmh) {
    cmh.commonMethod();
    // Do some stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you truly don't know what objects will be passed in and those object are not related through any kind of common base class or interface, then you will need to pass the object in as an `Object` reference and use reflection to find out if the object implements the method you want to call. If it does, then you again use reflection to call it.

Answer (score -1):

I understand a lot of people are interpreting your question to mean you want to know about interfaces but I am interpreting this "write a method which will take an unknown object as a parameter?" to mean how do I write a method to handle unknown objects. As the other answers already tell you unless they share a common interface you can't have them all call the same method. But in case you are asking for this(which is what I think your question is asking for) this is how you would custom handle different unknown parameters...

```
public void aMethod(Object... object) {
if(object==null)
{
    //whatever you want to do if no parameters are entered.
    return;
}
for (Object o : object) {
    if (o == null) {
    continue; //what to do if null entered
    }
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
    //whatever you want to do if it is an Integer
    }
    else if(o instanceof Double)
    {
    //whatever you want to do if it is a Double
    }
    else if(o instanceof Character)
    {
    //whatever you want to do if it is a Character
    }
    //and so on
 }
}
```

Comment: `Object...` would be an array of `Object`s. Why would you cast it to `int`?

Comment: @Christian Object... can also take nothing as well. I cast it to int to demonstrate how to handle it as another type. I am going to reedit it to explain more.

Comment: And how is it useful with the problem? Just asking.

Comment: @Christian according to how I am reading his question 'unknown object as a parameter?' means how do I create a method that can receive any data type.

Comment: The OP wants to call a common method on the object passed in. The Object class will not declare this method and so this won't work. The solution is to use an interface.

Comment: He will have to explicitly cast to the correct class before using the method. Also, I would use `Object` instead of `Object...`.

Comment: @Jason but he said an unknown object, what if he is passing in an int or a String? Can you still do that with an interface?

Comment: Cast to what? The interface? Why not just specify the interface instead of specifying Object and then forcing the cast?

Comment: If the object is truly unknown then he is going to need to use reflection to find if the required method exists.